# study on multiple outcomes- do I adjust or not adjust p-values?

Tags: statistical-significance

I did a study comparing 2 groups on multiple outcomes/characteristics. I am still learning the ropes when it comes to statistics,  so I failed to  specify to  adjust the p-values. Some of the results that came back were significant with unadjusted p-values   in the range of p=.00x and p=.0x (less than .05).

My question is: should I leave the results as is and just report the p-values as unadjusted?

Or if I need to re-run  tests with p-value adjustment , my question is this: The first time around, I included subcategories and subtests so the  number of outcomes measured had ballooned. If I need to re-run the analysis with an adjustment of p-value the second time around, I was planning to run it on only the composite measures, which streamlines the endpoints  of interest  to less than 10 ( by the way, this includes outcomes that came out both significant and non-significant  during the first analysis I did). What method of p-value  adjustment would you suggest? I understand that Bonferroni is the most conservative, but are their other adjustment methods that are less punishing?

Answer (score 4):

There are tons of post-hoc adjustment methods.  Whether adjustment is needed or not, and how to adjust is a matter of some debate.  You should reach a decision on these issues before conducting your analysis.  Contingent decision-making invalidates standard interpretations of p-values (e.g., [Wagenmakers, 2007](http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2007/pValueProblems.pdf)).  On a practical basis the "correct" answer depends quite a bit on the conventions in your field of study.  I quote extensively from another source below, but I think my short answer would be to use the Holm adjustment.  I think theoretically the false-discovery-rate approaches might make more sense, but I don't know how frequently people use them in practice.

Quoting from R's [help file on `p.adjust`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) for a sampling of the available options:

> adjustment methods include the Bonferroni correction ("bonferroni") in
>   which the p-values are multiplied by the number of comparisons. Less
>   conservative corrections are also included by Holm (1979) ("holm"),
>   Hochberg (1988) ("hochberg"), Hommel (1988) ("hommel"), Benjamini &
>   Hochberg (1995) ("BH" or its alias "fdr"), and Benjamini & Yekutieli
>   (2001) ("BY"), respectively.
>
> ...
>
> The first four methods are designed to give strong control of the
>   family-wise error rate. There seems no reason to use the unmodified
>   Bonferroni correction because it is dominated by Holm's method, which
>   is also valid under arbitrary assumptions.
>
> Hochberg's and Hommel's methods are valid when the hypothesis tests
>   are independent or when they are non-negatively associated (Sarkar,
>   1998; Sarkar and Chang, 1997). Hommel's method is more powerful than
>   Hochberg's, but the difference is usually small and the Hochberg
>   p-values are faster to compute.
>
> The "BH" (aka "fdr") and "BY" method of Benjamini, Hochberg, and
>   Yekutieli control the false discovery rate, the expected proportion of
>   false discoveries amongst the rejected hypotheses. The false discovery
>   rate is a less stringent condition than the family-wise error rate, so
>   these methods are more powerful than the others.

References (and commentary on same) from the r-help file:

- Benjamini, Y., and Hochberg, Y. (1995). Controlling the false discovery rate: a practical and powerful approach to multiple testing. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society Series B, 57, 289–300.
- Benjamini, Y., and Yekutieli, D. (2001). The control of the false discovery rate in multiple testing under dependency. Annals of Statistics 29, 1165–1188.
- Holm, S. (1979). A simple sequentially rejective multiple test procedure. Scandinavian Journal of Statistics, 6, 65–70.
- Hommel, G. (1988). A stagewise rejective multiple test procedure based on a modified Bonferroni test. Biometrika, 75, 383–386.
- Hochberg, Y. (1988). A sharper Bonferroni procedure for multiple tests of significance. Biometrika, 75, 800–803.
- Shaffer, J. P. (1995). Multiple hypothesis testing. Annual Review of Psychology, 46, 561–576. (An excellent review of the area.)
- Sarkar, S. (1998). Some probability inequalities for ordered MTP2 random variables: a proof of Simes conjecture. Annals of Statistics, 26, 494–504.
- Sarkar, S., and Chang, C. K. (1997). Simes' method for multiple hypothesis testing with positively dependent test statistics. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 92, 1601–1608.
- Wright, S. P. (1992). Adjusted P-values for simultaneous inference. Biometrics, 48, 1005–1013. (Explains the adjusted P-value approach.)

Comment: This is more an issue of data dredging than multiple testing. If you keep looking through multiple subgroups you will find associations, which may just be a remnant of the sample. Before you begin the analysis specify a primary hypothesis and  some pre-specified subgroup analysis. I tend not to adjust for multiple tests in practice for the subgroup analysis and justify it as exploratory (in epidemiological work it is difficult to pre-specify everything), but do mention that no adjustment has been made for multiple testing and that p-values are suggestive of an association.

Comment: Adjustment is necessary when pre-specified millions of tests;ie on genetic studies

Comment: Thank you both for your clarifications about my question. I appreciate it!

Comment: If your question was answered, please mark it as such.  If there is some element we still haven't addressed, please let us know.